# Likelihood Ratio Testing for Binomial Distributions

Tags: r, distributions, mathematical-statistics, likelihood-ratio

I have a feeling this is a silly question. I am working on a research paper, at some point in it we perform a likelihood ratio test. The first guess would be to apply Wilks's theorem. However, if we take the hypotheses:

$$
H_0: X_i\sim Binom(n1,p1), Y_i\sim Binom(n2,p2)
$$
$$
H_1: X_i\sim Binom(n1,p), Y_i\sim Binom(n2,p)
$$

Essentially, we are testing wether two binomial distributions, have the same parameter $p$. Now, please do not refer me to the standard way of testing this. This is a very simplified version of the problem and in the full problem the normal approximation is inaccurate. I have found a method for the test. So while I will appreciate suggestion for actually performing the test, this is not what I am looking for here. What I am asking:
Why $-2LLR$ under the null does not follow a $\chi^2_{1}$ distribution. Here is a [QQplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoGQz.png).

I tried to find out what part of Wilks's theorem assumptions is violated here. The parameters lie in the interior of the parameter space here $(0,1)$.   At this point I think that the answer must be either so obvious and I am looking too close to see the big picture, or must be some argument I don't have experience with ,either way I would like to be able to say why this is. Potentially my code is faulty. I appreciate any help/ resource I could get. Searching for papers answering this question has proven ineffective. Please be kind if this is obvious.

R code:

```
n1=100
n2=100

p1=0.5
p2=0.5

s=200

s1=rbinom(s,n1,p1)
s2=rbinom(s,n2,p2)



LLR= function(n1,s1,n2,s2) return(
                                  -log(choose(n1+n2,s1+s2))-((s1+s2)*log((s1+s2)/(n1+n2))+(n1+n2-s1-s2)*log(1-(s1+s2)/(n1+n2)))+
                                  (log(choose(n1,s1))+s1*log(s1/n1)+(n1-s1)*log(1-s1/n1))+
                                  (log(choose(n2,s2))+s2*log(s2/n2)+(n2-s2)*log(1-s2/n2))
                                 )

-2*LLR(n1,s1,n2,s2)


df=1

library(mgcViz)
y <- -2*LLR(n1,s1,n2,s2)
## Q-Q plot for Chi^2 data against true theoretical distribution:
qqplot(qchisq(ppoints(length(y)), df = df), y, main = expression("Q-Q plot for" ~~ {chi^2}[nu == 1]))

# Add qq line
library(ggplot2)
ggplot2::last_plot() + qqline(y, distribution = function(p) qchisq(p, df = df), prob = c(0.1, 0.6), col = 2)
```

Comment: Usually the null hypothesis sets the parameters equal to each other, not the alternative hypothesis. I see in the code you set both `p1=0.5` and `p2=0.5` so it's not a problem in your implementation, but it might be confusing for readers to see the usual notation changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in the statement `s=200`; this is not a large sample size for this experiment.  I've rewritten your code to make it a little clearer:

```
n1=100
n2=100

p <- 0.5
p1=0.5
p2=0.5

s = 100000

s1=rbinom(s,n1,p1)
s2=rbinom(s,n2,p2)

llr <- rep(0, length(s1))
  
for (i in 1:length(s1)) {
  phat0 <- (s1[i] + s2[i]) / (n1 + n2)
  llf1 <- sum(dbinom(s1[i], n1, phat0, log=TRUE)) + sum(dbinom(s2[i], n2, phat0, log=TRUE))
  phat1 <- s1[i] / n1
  phat2 <- s2[i] / n2
  llf2 <- sum(dbinom(s1[i], n1, phat1, log=TRUE)) + sum(dbinom(s2[i], n2, phat2, log=TRUE))
    
  llr[i] <- llf1 - llf2
}

y <- -2*llr

library(ggplot2)
qqplot(qchisq(ppoints(length(y)), df = 1), y, main = expression("Q-Q plot for" ~~ {chi^2}[nu == 1]))
ggplot2::last_plot() + qqline(y, distribution = function(p) qchisq(p, df = 1), prob = c(0.05, 0.95), col = 2)
```

With a sample size of 100,000, we get the following plot:

[image]

Obviously not a perfect fit, but then again, a) we are dealing with a discrete underlying distribution, and b) the result is an asymptotic one.

Is this test still useful?  A quick comparison of the observed probability of rejecting the (true) null hypothesis that the two probabilities are equal:

- $\alpha = 0.10$:  observed reject rate = 0.1039
- $\alpha = 0.05$: observed reject rate = 0.0562
- $\alpha = 0.01$: observed reject rate = 0.0091

These are all quite close to their nominal levels, indicating that the likelihood ratio test pretty much achieves its targeted type I rejection rate.  It appears to me to be a useful test, asymptotic though it is, given the sample size.

Comment: I see, however that explains why the test doesn't work, these "hitches" are substantial, is it safe to say it is a bad idea anyway?  Also the tail distributions are dubious. Thank you.

Comment: I've added a paragraph to address this point.  The test works fine; those hitches are really quite small, and a half dozen observations in the tail with 100,000 overall observations don't really matter.